# How to securely combine multiple sources of entropy?

Tags: keys, key-derivation, entropy, pbkdf-2, information-theory

Suppose that I have $n$ secure 32-bit keys that were generated separately using methods that are known to be secure. For example, one of them might have been generated by using a proven CSPRNG. Another may have been generated using PBKDF2.

Now, I want to turn *all* of these keys, combined together in to a new key that I can use to encrypt and decrypt data.

The important thing is that I want to require *all* of the keys to be present in order to perform the encryption and decryption.

What I want to know is, what is the best way to combine these keys and maintain the highest level of security against attacks?

For example, I could just concatenate all the 32-bit keys and then run them through PBKDF2 again:

```
# pbkdf2(key, salt, iterations, derived_key_length)
# Also, "a + b" indicates concatenating a + b as strings, i.e. "hello" + " world" = "hello world"

new_key = pbkdf2(key1 + key2 + key3, some_salt, 10000, 32)
```

Or, instead of concatenating them, I could concatenate some of them in the salt:

```
new_key = pbkdf2(key1, key2 + key3, 10000, 32)
```

Or, I could iteratively run pbkdf2:

```
temp_key = pbkdf2(key1, key2, 10000, 32)
new_key = pbkdf2(key3, temp_key, 10000, 32)
```

Or, I could concatenate them all and hash them:

```
new_key = sha1(key1 + key2 + key3)
```

Or, I could iteratively hash them with concatenated versions of the previous hash:

```
a = sha1(key1)
b = sha1(a + key2)
new_key = sha1(b + key3)
```

Or, I could produce a hash using one of the above methods and *then* run that hash through PBKDF2:

```
hash = sha1(key1 + key2 + key3)
new_key = pbkdf2(hash, some_salt, 10000, 32)
```

Or, I could xor them all together:

```
new_key = xor(xor(key1, key2), key3)
```

Or, xor them all together, and then run though pbkdf2, etc. etc.

Clearly there are a ton of ways to combine these keys to produce a new secure key.

Is there any prior work on this? What is the best and most secure way to do this?

If any of the above methods are *not* secure, can you explain why?

P.S. As an additional aspect of this question, I am curious if the "password" or the "salt" are more or less secure places to put entropy. For example, are both of the following equally secure?

```
new_key = pbkdf2(key1 + key2, key3, 10000, 32)
```

and

```
new_key = pbkdf2(key1, key2 + key3, 10000, 32)
```

Comment: not XOR them together, as the result would only be a 32-bit value, and thus insecure, and not iteratively hash with concatenated versions of the previous, as that can be optimized. a KDF can be functionally replaced with iterative hashing, but I would use some function that uses more memory, like HKDF-expand per Luis's answer, say 65536 outputs of SHA-512, then hash the outputs in reverse order. It will be slow like PBKDF but use too much memory for optimized parallel attacks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your keys, taken together, have sufficient entropy to support your desired security level, then [HKDF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) ([paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/264.pdf)) is a conservative solution here, because it assumes that the input keying material to the `HKDF-extract` might not be uniformly distributed.

The most conservative way of using it in your case would be to supply the concatenation of your keys as the `IKM` ("input keying material") parameter to `HKDF-extract`, and do not use the optional salt.  Then either use the `PRK` result directly, or as a further input to the `HKDF-expand` function.

A less conservative way of using it, if you are confident your inputs are indistinguishable from uniform random and mutually independent, would be to skip the `HKDF-extract` function supply the concatenated input directly to `HKDF-expand`.

Comment: Can you explain the advantage of HKDF over other alternatives for this specific usage?  Also, can you explain why concatenation is a sufficient way to merge the keys pre-HKDF?

Comment: Specifically, I'm curious what advantage HKDF has over PBKDF2 in this scenario.

Comment: @SamSmith: See [this answer of mine to another question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40406/choosing-between-simple-hash-and-hkdf-to-derive-the-second-key-used-for-mac/40431#40431).  But to reiterate, the key word in the answer I gave you is "conservative"—HKDF assumes the input has sufficient entropy to support your security level, but doesn't assume that it's uniform or that its bits are independent. That's also why concatenation is sufficient for merging inputs to HKDF.

Comment: @SamSmith: If your inputs have sufficient entropy to support your security level, then there's no advantage to using a slow, password-based function like PBKDF2.

Comment: HKDF seems like it's too fast for this - Someone who knows all-but-one of the 32-bit keys would only need to run in 2^32 times. ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: The way I read the question, we're allowed to assume that the 32-bit keys are all secret. I did assume however that we have at least four, that none of them is strongly predictive of the others, and that their entropy is close to the stated 32 bits.  I'll edit the response to clarify.

Comment: "The important thing is that" he wants "to require _all_ of the keys to be present in order to perform the encryption and decryption." ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Are you reading that as implying that the keys are held by separate, adversarial parties? I am not. If you are reading it right, however, then your objection to my answer holds.

Comment: No, I'm reading that as specifying that an adversary might gain access to a subset of the keys. ​ (I now realize that my reading requires that the "secure" in "$n$ secure 32-bit keys" just refer to their _generation_ rather than how they're kept.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguity. When I said "n secure 32-bit keys" I meant that they were generated properly.  The idea here is that you would want to require an adversary to have all of the keys before they could access the data. If they only got 2/3 of the keys, for example, they should not be able to access the data without the third.

Comment: @SamSmith The problem is that 32-bits is much too small for a key that's secure by itself, even when combined with an expensive password hash. The attacker can simply brute-force one missing key.

Comment: @CodesInChaos What if we said each key was 128-bits? How would that change the answer?

Comment: @SamSmith Using 128-bit keys, leaving even one of them out would make brute-forcing the key infeasible on today's hardware.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If they were 128 bit keys, what would be the best way to combine them?

Comment: @SamSmith : ​ Do you want to defend against an adversary changing one of the keys? $\hspace{1.03 in}$ If no, then [bitwise xor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR). ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Meh, why have 128 bits of security while you can have $n$ times 128 bit security? HKDF and concatenation is at least as good and for very little computational overhead.